# width: inherit and float: none redundant?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

In a tutorial for responsive design a pattern reoccurs many times:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px){
    .class1{
        width: inherit;
        float: none;
        }
    .class2{
        width: inherit;
        float: none;
        }
```

for two the two classes which were set to `float: left` in a parent container.
I am just wondering: is this code redundant? If the width is set to `inherit` , there is no way for any other element to float around it, or do i miss anything?

**Edit** Thanks to @BoltClock here are some examples where there is a difference

If the children are in a block context, it does not `float: none;` is not necessary:

http://jsfiddle.net/rCwnx/2/

In an inline context `float: left` looks broken:

http://jsfiddle.net/TkJA7/

while `float: none` provides the desired result

http://jsfiddle.net/Z5RHX/

Comment: @André Dion: No, the "Inherited: no" portion just means that it doesn't inherit by default. You can still force it to inherit using the `inherit` keyword.

Comment: It depends on the HTML markup and on other CSS rules whether the setting is redundant. In general, it is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not necessarily redundant. It completely depends on the layout of the floats and their containers.

If the parent of these elements does not establish a [block formatting context](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#block-formatting), other elements outside of the parent can still be affected by these elements if they continue to float, even though they may inherit the full computed width of their parent.

Within the parent element itself, floating an element takes it out of the normal flow, which can also cause undesirable side effects for other elements inside the parent. For example, following siblings in the normal flow would be positioned as if that element wasn't there, with their text starting just underneath it.